# Moodle 2.2.3 getting error when executing it in command line

Tags: cron, syntax-error, moodle

I'm doing a Moodle 2.2.3 installation and I can't get the cron job to work. I have the crontab configured, and I have even tested it with other scripts and it works.

The problem I believe is that even when I try to manually execute the cron script by doing this in the command line:

```
php /kunden/homepages/44/d******/htdocs/moodle/moodle-223/admin/cli/cron.php
```

I get this error:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in <b>/homepages/44/d******/htdocs/moodle/moodle-223/lib/setup.php</b> on line <b>658</b><br />
```

What brings my attention is the first line: **PHP/4.4.9**

Does that mean that the PHP version is that 4.4.9? Because we supposedly have PHP 5.4 in our shared hosting (1&1). If I run php_info() from any website I get PHP version 5.4.4...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok so what I've had to do is to force **php6** when calling the script like:

```
/usr/bin/php6 /kunden/homepages/44/d******/htdocs/moodle/moodle-223/admin/cli/cron.php
```

In the crontab I put exactly that same line as a command, and it seems to work.